# Is it ok to state in my question that any user is allowed to edit my title to fit the question?

Tags: discussion, questions, title

I'm currently writing a question on the main site, however I'm finding it very hard to set a title.

Would it be ok if I added a text in the question that states that if someone finds a good title fit for the question, they are more than welcome to edit the title?

I don't really know how "sensitive" the editing of titles are. But I assume that editing a title is often made to correct spelling and such. In this case it would involve changing most of the title.

Comment: Protip:  Skip the title until after you finish and edit your question.  Often it will pop into focus at that point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Everyone is **always** welcome to edit the title, no need to add meta-info to your question. Focus on the meat instead.

If I see an opportunity to give a question a better title, I won't hesitate to do so.

On the other hand, if I see such meta-info in a question, then I'd edit that out immediately. Such extra information is really just noise, not helpful to future visitors of your question, and distracts from the issue at hand.

If you are really embarassed by your lack of titling skills, at best add a comment to your own question, stating that you'd welcome a better title. Meta info like this is best left to comments, deleting them after you did get a better title is easy.

Comment: Thanks, i'll probably restrain myself from adding such meta information in my questsions from now on!

Answer (score 1):

Everyone can suggest an edit for your title.

Everyone that has the privilege can edit your title.

If you feel it needs another name, and you can't find it, you may mention it.